# What does "transform among themselves" mean?

Tags: group-theory, transformation, rotations, tensors

I'm reading a script on atomic physics, and there's a chapter on irreducible tensors. I can't understand the meaning of "transform among themselves" in this context:

> An arbitrary rotation of the coordinate frame will transform the
>   tensor $T$ into a tensor $T'$, whose components $T_{ij}'$ are, in the most
>   general case, linear combinations of all the components $T_{ij
> }$.
>   However, it is always possible to find certain subgroups of the
>   components $T_{ij}$ (formed by linear combinations thereof) **that transform
>   among themselves** under a rotation. These components are called the
>   irreducible tensor components.

Can you please explain that scientifically and linguistically?

Comment: script???????????????????

Comment: As a mathematician, I like physics very much and I've always wanted to learn physics. But unfortunately it is sometimes impossible to understand the mathematics physicists use. You just encountered one instance here. It is not your fault, what the author has written is not clear.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh Thank you; that helps and makes me not feel stupid :-) ; though if you google the term "transform among themselves" you'll find it in wikipedia and some other websites... which was puzzling for me!

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh: I think any applied area is like that. In any given field, some topics are fundamental and dealt with rigorously, some are treated with blatant disregard. Knowing which is which is an art.

Comment: Should I repose this question in a physics forum?

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80313/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that a subgroup $S$ (which a mathematician would call a subset, as it's not a group in the technical sense) of tensor components transform among themselves means that, if $T_{ij}$ is any one of the components in $S$, then the corresponding $T'_{ij}$ is a linear combination of components $T_{kl}$ from $S$, as opposed to being a linear combination of just any old components of $T$.  So one can write down the transformation rules for the components in $S$ without ever mentioning any other components.